# Can't open any txt file in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I am trying to open a txt file (the textfile contains coordinates. It has a x and y column) within ArcMap 10.0. But everytime I want to open it (Add data --> Add XY Data) the software does not show me the X and Y field. Even when I try to open the txt via Data -> Add Data --> Add Data I get an error message "General function failure".
Even when I try to create a txt file like done in http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1%20/index.html#//005s00000010000000 I am experiencing the same problems. The same happens also if I convert the txt to csv.

Does anybody have an idea why I can't open any txt file in Arcmap?

Edit: I can open the file in ArcMap on my computer at home. Only on my works computer I am experiencing the problem that I can't open any text file. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the data correctly formatted? This could lead to this error.

Comment: You might post a few lines from the file to help us see what the issue is.

Comment: A few years ago I discovered a weird thing with Arcmap. If your CSV file is on the root of your C:\ drive Arcmap never shows it. As soon as you move it to a folder such as c:\Temp then its visible and you can add it to the map and display as an event layer. Is this the issue?

Comment: @Hornbydd Works fine for me in the not-yet-released 10.4.0 prerelease!

Comment: @mkennedy just tested in on my PC at home which in Windows 10 running ArcMap 10.2.1 and the CSV does not appear if on root but if moved into a sub-folder you see it! All a bit "twilight zone" if you ask me... :)

Comment: Yeah. Do share a portion of ur text file
and check when u assign XY to fields through ADD XY DATA...
It should matched.

Comment: @Hornbydd The problem is still present after moving the file to a subfolder. There shouldn't be any formatting issue because I tested the same file on my home computer and it opens fine in ArcMap. Only on my works pc I am experiencing this problem. No txt file is openable. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dominic, could there be a difference in setup between both computers, where one (at home) is using "." as the decimal separator, and the other (at work) is using "," ? Then your values would be recognized as coordinates or not, because they would be interpreted as numeric or text.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others, this sounds like a formatting issue. Make sure your TXT file is correctly formatted and there are no strange characters in it.

Can you post a screenshot or an excerpt of the TXT file?